# Moment-generating function of random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \delta_2(x) + \frac{1}{2} \lambda e^{- \lambda x}$ where $\delta_2(x) = 1  \Leftrightarrow x=2$ and $\delta_2(x) = 0  \Leftrightarrow x \neq 2$.

How prove that $M_X(t) = \frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda}(t) + \frac{1}{2}M_{\delta}(t)$ where of course:

$M_{\lambda}(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t} \\ M_{\delta}(t) = e^{2t}$

Comment: $f(x)$ is the density function? If so, $\delta_2(x)$ is a Dirac delta? If yes, the definition is wrong. If no, (if the definition is right) it should not influence the result (so it's wrong). Is this homework? Don't you need to study a little more the theory before asking for help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the integral of the expectation. $E[e^{tX}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}\ \delta_2(x) dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \frac{1}{2}M_\delta(t)+\frac{1}{2}M_\lambda(t)$.

I think that you can finish it yourself from here on.